# SQL query to check if files of the extension type (file) is available at a particular folder location

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, file-extension, file-exists

I've written the below code

create proc Getfilestatus as 
begin

```
 set nocount on
 create table #tempFileStatus(Filepath varchar(300), FileStatus varchar(30))
 declare cur cursor local fast_forward for
         (select filepath from dbo.Directory)

 open cur;
 declare @fullpath varchar(250);
 declare @isExists int;

 fetch from cur into @fullpath
 while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

      begin

          exec xp_fileexist @fullpath, @isExists out
          if @isExists =1
              insert into #tempFileStatus values (@fullpath, 'File exist')
          else
              insert into #tempFileStatus values (@fullpath, 'File does not exist')
          fetch from cur into @fullpath

      end

   close cur
   deallocate cur
   select * from #tempFileStatus

   drop table #tempFileStatus
```

end

I've executed the procedure as exec GetFileStatus

But, even though files are present in the location, when i execute this code, the output displays File does not exist

The files that I'm trying to check and flat files and the extension of the file is 'file'

Comment: The file should be present at the server where SQL is installed. Also, filename should be complete. For eg, C:\\ABC\\YourFile.file

Comment: @Atk yes my files are present in the server where SQL is installed

Comment: What's there in your variable @fullpath?

Comment: @Atk the file path is in my full path variable